# Local CSS won't even show up in Inspector

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I'm building a website with Bootstrap and I also have a local CSS stylesheet I'm using for specific cases. It has worked alright so far, but for some reason, new classes I'm adding won't work. I've tried a number of things already and nothing gives. The class is not even showing up in the inspector (see picture).

[image]

What I've tried:

- Clearing cache
- Trying to be more specific than Bootstrap
- Adding type text/css and media all

Here's the basic CSS:

```
p.description {
  color: red;
}
```

And here is a snippet of the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/auto-complete.css" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/css/style.css?rnd=28" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/css/all.css" media="all" />
  </head>

<body class="bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <main>
      <div class="row g-5">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-12">
          <form  class="needs-validation" action="dbcmds/ajout-outil.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="activity" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="row g-3">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p class="description">Description</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
```

All suggestions welcome! I could inline the CSS but I'd rather do it properly... and understand what's going on!

Many thanks!

Edit------

Here's the structure of the project. The current page is in the admin directory.

[image]

Comment: instead of ../ write ./

Comment: No that's alright, I'm one directory up in the tree so I have to go down one before I go to public.

Comment: Can you provide the project structure? You can attach a image with your question.

Comment: @Mugen check your network tab in the dev tools to see if the files are correctly linked, if not then your href are not correct

Comment: Everything is linked just fine. In fact I have a class defined in my styles on this page that works perfectly...

Comment: In your image, your style.css is in styles/style.css while in your html code you have linked to files with css/style.css

Comment: Holy mother of God... I have a duplicate style.css file!! In another directory... I'll be damned. Thank you!!! 

Answer (score 0):

Go straight for the route method:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/auto-complete.css"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/style.css?rnd=28"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/all.css"/>
```

Also, I have never seen the `media="all"` used before, try without.